# how to keep user login state when the broswer is reload ? (react-redux)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Now i'm using localstorage to keep user login.

```
// App.js
...
const token = localstorage.getItem('token');
useEffect(()=> {
if(token) {
 setSignState(true);
} else {
setSignState(false);
}, [token])
```

But i'm not sure about my way to handle this problem.
so, is there more effective way to keep user login whenever reload ?

Comment: No, this is the way

Comment: take a look at redux-offline library. It's the same principle though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you check out `session Storage` instead.  It works just like `localStorage` but it would reset when the user closes the tab or the browser window.  This is better for security reasons,  as if the user shares a PC or is using a public device and forgets to log out properly. Also make sure you check if the use r is logged in in the server side session as well, otherwise someone can change the value of the `localStorage` variable on the client side